# im getting TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable on my chat bot

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, chatbot

im currently building a chat bot for a project and it showed me an error that i could find nothing helpful about

heres the main function

```
def AXIS():
  knowledge_base:dict = open('knowledge_base.json','r',errors = 'ignore')
  while True:
    user_input:str = input('You:')
    if user_input.lower() in ("q", "quit", "shut down", "shutdown", "cancel", "power off", "poweroff", "power down", "powerdown", "off", "turn off", "turnoff"):
      print("AXIS: powering down")
      break

    best_match: str | None = find_best_match(user_input, list['q("question") for q in knowledge_base.json("questions")'])
    if best_match:
      answer: str = get_answer_for_question(best_match, knowledge_base)
      print(f'AXIS: {answer}')
    else:
      print('AXIS: I don\'t know the answer. please teach me?')
      new_answer: str = input('Type the answer or "skip" to skip:  ')
      if new_answer.lower() != 'skip':
        knowledge_base["questions"].append({"question": user_input, "answer": new_answer})
        save_knowledge_base('knowledge_base.json', knowledge_base)
        print('AXIS: I have learned a new response!')

if __name__ =='__main__':
  AXIS()
```

i dont know where to start in fixing this problem

knowledge_base is very simple currently and is shown below.

```
{
  "questions": [
    
  ]
}
```

knowledge base builds on itself as you teach the chat bot

here is the other functions

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches
```

```
def save_knowledge_base(file_path: str, data: dict):
  with open(file_path,'w')as file:
    json.dump(data,file, indent=2)
```

```
def find_best_match(user_question: str, questions: list[str]):
  return str | None
  matches: list = get_close_matches(user_question, questions, n=1, cutoff=0.6)
  return matches[0] if matches else None
```

```
def get_answer_for_question(question: str, knowledge_base: dict):
  for q in knowledge_base["questions"]:
    if q["question"] == question:
      return q["answer"]
```

i was following a youtube tutorial to build it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkkjXTER2KE

heres the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-46ef27f29e5d> in <cell line: 21>()
     20 
     21 if __name__ =='__main__':
---> 22   AXIS()

1 frames
<ipython-input-4-00a332bc4e21> in get_answer_for_question(question, knowledge_base)
      1 def get_answer_for_question(question: str, knowledge_base: dict):
----> 2   for q in knowledge_base["questions"]:
      3     if q["question"] == question:
      4       return q["answer"]

TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: what does knowledgebase.json look like ? No one can help without that...

Comment: just edited that in thank you for telling me. @MattEvans

Comment: and which library are you referencing find_best_match from?

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Where do you the functions `load_knowledge_base` and `save_knowledge_base` come from?

Comment: edited the rest of the code in @9769953

Answer (score 1):

`knowledge_base("questions")`: you're *calling* the dict; perhaps you wanted square brackets instead: `knowledge_base["questions"]`?

Although that mistake should not lead to the error message you get. But you are telling people that `knowledge_base` is a dict in line 26. So perhaps it is a derived type? What is `type(knowledge_base)`?

---

I noticed the following:

```
def load_knowledge_base(file_path: str):
  return dict
  ...
```

You're returning a type!
I doubt if that's intended. Perhaps just simply remove that line?

It definitely explains the error message. If you return an actual instantiated dict, not the type, you'll run into the error I mention at the top. So you have at least two things to fix.

Comment: i just tried deleting it and basicaly it told me i needed it there so the rest of  function can access the dictionary.

how would i return the instantiated dict.

Comment: i just edited it so it shows the type of dictionary hope it helps. unless i did it wrong and if so please tell me

Comment: @thewatcher Did you remove *only* the line `return dict`?

Comment: yes and once i do that it cant find the knowledge_base.json file. if there is a way get the program to find it withought the return dict ill happily try it

Comment: If it can't find the file, that is another problem, and it probably means the path is correct. You never had that problem before, because you never got to the stage of reading the file with the first problem. Double check the file name, and try also with a full path.

Comment: thank you for the help i seem to have fixed all the code stopping errors but a new problem has arisin.